# How to check if outside of a div clicked without using stopPropagation and target event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to follow multiple div elements and check if outside of one of these divs clicked. I would like to do that without using **stopPropagation** (because it has effect on other page elements) and **event.target** (because it is not working on ie7 and ie8).

Is there another solution to check if outside of multiple elements is clicked?

What I am trying to do is : As click on one div, add clicked div an class(active) and if outside of active div is clicked //do sth 
P.S: The div is has 'nonActive' class is a outside...

What I did so far..

```
$('.box').addClass('nonActive'); 
var activeBox = "";
$('.box').on("click",function() {
    activeBox = $(this);
    activeBox.addClass('active');

});
$(document).on("click", function() {
   if(!activeBox.hasClass('active')){
      activeBox.hide();
   }else{
      alert('active');
   }
});
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/hcwz4cgd/1/

Comment: Still supporting IE7. Developers please^n stop supporting it then only we can move forward.

Comment: @Satpal I'm sure we'd love to, however it's down to the client that pays the bills what level of support is required.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, You have to convice your client. As we did now we only support IE9+.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by listening on document click also and setting a flag 'clicked' on the target to true, so when the normal event handler is called and bubbled, I check this variable

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hcwz4cgd/

```
var clickout = true,
  mybox = $('#mybox, .anyselectoryouwish');
mybox.on("click",function() {
    clickout = false;
   console.log('box click');
   mybox.removeClass('active');// remove class on all followed elements
   $(this).addClass('active');// add class on active element
});
$(document).on("click", function() {
   if(clickout){
          console.log('clickout : ', mybox);
          mybox.removeClass('active');// remove class on all followed elements
   }
   else  clickout = true;
});
```

Edit
watch comments in previous code

Comment: I thought same thing and tried to come up with a solution however, I still can't figure out how to point the div 'as a target element' without using event.target as you are doing on your example..

Comment: do you have many elements to 'follow' ? if not, you don't have to point it trought the event, you know it one time for all and target it when needed

Comment: see my edit, just store the element with the selector you need, there is only 2 case : clicked inside one of the elements or not at all, you cannot say clicked outside *this* particular element

Comment: I understand your point however I do need to declare _this_ as a particular element..But you gave me an idea sure I am working on it..

Comment: so you have to re formulate you question as we can't just guess all the particular cases you need, and again clickout outside a specific element is a non sense, either one is clicked, either none...

Comment: You are right! I have changed it..thnx for your time anyway!